# Bootstrap navigation bar not right when collapsed

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar, nav

So I've changed the css so that the navigation bar's height matches the logo's height. It works great but when I collapse it to mobile view, there is a line that's bothering me, look at the picture:

This is normal destop version:
[image]

This is collapsed mobile view:
[image]

This is collapsed mobile view when I press the burger menu. **This is the problem, the grey line is out**:
[image]

This is my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <title> Mobtech </title>

        <!--Ubaci bootstrap css -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

    </head>
    <body>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-container">
                        <span class="sr-only"> Pokazi i sakrij navigaciju </span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                        <img src="Slike/logo.png" alt="LogoSlika"/>
                    </a>
                </div> 
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-container">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li class="active"><a href="#"> Početna strana </a> </li>
                        <li><a href="#"> Privatni korisnici </a> </li>
                        <li><a href="#"> Poslovni korisnici </a> </li>
                        <li><a href="#"> Uređaji </a> </li>
                        <li><a href="#"> O Nama </a> </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>

        <br />
            <div class="container"> <!--Container -->

                <div class="row">
                    <!-- Kolona na velikom ekranu (lg) prikazuje duzinu jedne kolone, Ekstra small (xs) prikazuje 4 kolone -->
                    <div class="col-lg-12 bg-success"> 
                        <p> Outer div </p>
                        <div class="col-lg-6 bg-primary">
                            <p> Inner div </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>




            <!-- JavaScript fajl -->
            <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <!-- Kompresovan JavaScript fajl -->
            <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


            <!-- bg-warning = Pozadina zuta -->
    </body>
</html>
```

This is my css:

```
    .navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a  {
    padding: 21px 15px 21px 15px;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
    padding-top: 0px;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .navbar-nav > li > a {
    line-height: 21px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;}
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .navbar-default {
    line-height: 21px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 11px;}
}
```

Comment: .navbar has default min-height: 50px . So you may set the logo image max-height. Like this : .navbar-brand > img{ max-height: 45px }

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution:

1. Open bootstrap.min.css file
2. Search for this code:

   ```
   container-fluid>.navbar-collapse,
   .container-fluid>.navbar-header,
   .container>.navbar-collapse,
   .container>.navbar-header {
       margin-right:-15px;
       margin-left:-15px

   }
   ```
3. Add `height:150px` to the end of the above code.

   After adding the code it may like this:

   ```
   container-fluid>.navbar-collapse,
   .container-fluid>.navbar-header,
   .container>.navbar-collapse,
   .container>.navbar-header {
       margin-right:-15px;
       margin-left:-15px;
       height:150px;
   }
   ```
4. Then save and check again.

Comment: I'm not saying that this wouldn't work, but is not a good way to proceed. Overriding using the cascading behavior of CSS is a much better option.

Comment: Changing the code of ready made libraries and hardcode user desired properties, is really bad practice and should always be avoided. Instead you could suggest of overriding those properties by adding a `<style>` element or a new CSS file.